# Windows Service never call OnStop() method when shutdown

Tags: c#

I have simplest possible windows service.

I need service to run under **Local System** account.

If I start/stop service from SCM, everything works fine, my log text file has both Start and Stop events, and also both Start and Stop events are shown automatically in the event viewer.

But **when I restart or shutdown my PC** (tried with Win 7 and Win 10), **OnStop() method is never called**, if service runs as **Local System** account. If I change account to Network Service or any other Local/Domain account, OnStop() method is called before restart/shutdown of the PC.

Windows service code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace SimplestService
{
    class MyService : ServiceBase
    {
        private string path = "<pathtologfile>\\MyServiceLog.txt";

        public MyService()
        {
            this.ServiceName = "MyService";
            this.CanShutdown = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("MyService Started.");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("MyService Stopped.");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
            OnStop();
        }
    }
}
```

and Main Entry:

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace SimplestService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(new MyService());
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity I've used SC utility to create service, even though I tried with Installer, even setup project (msi), but with same results.

```
sc create MyService binPath= "<pathtoexe>\SimplestService.exe"
type= own start= auto DisplayName= Myservice
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Windows has added an option called `Fast Startup` which does not actually shutdown the computer.

As noted in the `Fast Startup` setting description, `Restart` isn't affected. This is why the `Restart` triggers `OnShutdown` and `Shutdown` does not.

Turning off `Fast Startup` will trigger `OnShutdown` for both `Restart` and `Shutdown`.

[image: Power Options System Settings]

Answer (score 3):

From what I researched, the OnShutdown method is called when the OS is shutdown, but there is there is a strict time limit, but i believe the local system services are terminated even before this time limit so that OS shutdown time is fast. This might explain why domain account are shutdown slower. Windows has introduced a PreShutdown event to handle this.
Try the link below, it has more information on this
https://www.atomia.com/2011/11/16/how-to-process-the-preshutdown-event-in-a-managed-windows-service/